# Is there any away to create STI child model objects from the STI base class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Given the following hierarchy

```
class Content < ActiveRecord::Base end
class Page < Content end
class Post < Content end
```

Is it possible to create for example, Page content (indirectly) using the following style:

c = Content.new
c.type = Page
c.title = 'test'
c.save!

Looks like type is also a ruby method on the object.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Definitely, but you have to use write_attribute

```
c.write_attribute(:type, "Page")
c.save
```

Comment: wat's the difference between c.type = Page, c.write_attribute(:type, "Page") and c.send(:type=, "Page"). I believe understandingly all these three methods are doing is setting @type = "Page", isn't it? Also is there going to be any problem if I define my own getter and setter methods for type, which overrides the object.type method ?

Comment: on second check, c.type = "Page" is exactly equivalent to c.write_attribute(:type, "Page").  The key thing is that it has to be a string value.  As long as your override of type still returns sensible values, you should be fine.  You can also change the STI column by changing the value of inheritance_column.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend doing something like this...

```
klass = "Page"
klass.constantize.create(:title=>'title')
```

If you just monkey around with the 'type' attribute, you won't have any methods you override in the subclass in your object.